# Derivative of special function in R

Tags: r

I have the following formula:

[image]

where `T` is transpose and I want to calculate the first derivative of the above function with respect to x. How can I do it in R?

```
        x = c(1, 2)
        y = cbind(y1, y2)
        y1 = runif(n = 100, -2, 2)
        y2 = rbinom(n = 100, 1, 0.5)
```

At the end I need four values which is the derivative with respect to x.

Comment: So you want 4 partial derivatives? What is "n"? And what purpose are the random samples supposed to be serving? (Do you really know what you are doing?)

Comment: Yes, 4 partial derivaties. Just I gave an example for producing result.

Comment: Not sure I understand your formula and/or code. It looks like `x` is 4x1, and `y` is 100x2. I can't see how `x^T y_i` is defined in this case.

Comment: Okay, with your edit, `x` is now 2x1. The crossproduct still doesn't make much sense, assuming f is supposed to be a scalar quantity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [numDeriv](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numDeriv/index.html) to calculate numerical derivatives. So you would do this:

```
library("numDeriv")
lapply(x, function(z) grad(f, z))
```

to calculate it at 
What is `T`? If `T` is a constant, you can calculate the derivative analytically, the result is

[image]

and calculate it directly.